# foreach loop for display data in elements, for json whit multiple array

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I have a json from an external domain, I need to create a list of posts, and I have to write the data taken from json in elements

```
{
            "dati": [

        {
            "id": 98762,
            "tipo": "eventi",
            "titolo": “TITOLO 1“,
            "sottotitolo": "",
            "img": "http://www.asdsad.it",
            "url": "http://www.asdsad.it",
            "data_da": "2016-01-05",
            "data_a": "2016-01-05",
            "stato": "IT",
            "regione": "IT.10",
            "provincia": "IT.10.FM",
            "citta": "Porto Sant\'Elpidio",
            "indirizzo": "Via Faleria, 15"
        },
        {
            "id": 97004,
            "tipo": "corsi",
            "titolo": “TITOLO 2”,
            "sottotitolo": "",
            "img": “http://www.asdsad.it”,
            "url": "http://www.asdsad.it",
            "data_da": "2016-01-05",
            "data_a": "2016-01-05",
            "stato": "IT",
            "regione": "IT.08",
            "provincia": "IT.08.SV",
            "citta": "Savona",
            "indirizzo": ""
        }
            ]
        }
```

the result will be somenthing like that:

```
<div id="98762">
<h1>TITOLO 1</h1>
<img src="http://www.asdsad.it" />
<h3>eventi<h3/>
......
</div> 

<div id="97004">
<h1>TITOLO 2</h1>
<h3>corsi<h3/>
<img src="http://www.asdsad.it" />
......
</div>
```

I have try whit this but i get a blank page..

```
<?php 
$data = file_get_contents("url_json");
$dataArray = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($dataArray as $row){
    foreach ($row as $key => $value){
        switch ($key) {
            case 'id':
              echo  "<div> $value </div>";
            break;
            case 'sottotitolo':
              echo  "<h3> $value </h3>";
            break;
            case 'img':
              echo  "<img src=$value >";
            break;
           // ...
        }

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($dataArray);var_dump($row);`

Comment: echo $data; getting this?

Comment: Your json string is invalid. wrong quotes in `“TITOLO 1“`. Test and validate your json string [here](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: echo $data   work, ill output all json

Comment: “http://www.asdsad.it” ?? quotes?

Comment: json is ok, i've just edit wrong for delete link and title...

Answer (score 0):

i thing you have an error in json file.Try to fix that one first.After that if you are getting " `$dataArray`" properly you can use this

```
$data = file_get_contents("url_json");
$dataArray = json_decode($data, true);
$append_str = '';
foreach ($dataArray['dati'] as $row) {
    $append_str .= '<div id="' . $row['id'] . '">'
            . '<h1>' . $row['sottotitolo'] . '</h1>'
            . '<img src="' . $row['img'] . '" />'
            . '</div> ';
}

echo $append_str;
```

Comment: it will fail for this index “TITOLO 1“

Comment: look the json i have link, it's been validated... but i don't know why the code posted by Nimshad doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove **“** and **”** than you will get the result in `jsqon_decode()`;

You can try this (**Example is just for specific issue**):

```
$data = file_get_contents("url_json");
$data = str_replace('“', '"', $data); // replace “ with "
$data = str_replace('”', '"', $data); // replace ” with "
$dataArray = json_decode($data, true);
```